# callback function confusion in general

Tags: c, callback

I am very confused about callback function. Specifically I am confused about the order of the functions being called in the sequence of functions that make use of callback functions.

For example, I have this piece of code and problem in a question that I recently done, and the solution is below:

> The procedure `nthPrime` shown below computes the nth prime number asynchronously; i.e., it returns
> immediately and then calls callback sometime later with the value of the requested prime number. Give
> code below that uses this procedure to print the product of the 100th and 200th prime numbers without spinwaiting
> or polling (i.e., your code must call this procedure twice and multiply the results). You can use global
> variables in your solution if you like.
>
> `void nthPrime(int n, void (*callback)(int));`

So the solution is:

```
int t;
void nthPrime(int n, void (*callback)(int));
void foo(int n) {
    nthPrime(100, a);
}
void a(int p) {
    t = p;   // why assign p to t here?  
    nthPrime(200, b);
}
void b(int p) {
    printf("%d\n", t * p);  // t*p, but what is p here? 
}
```

However I am totally confused about how the solution (or functions above is being used to implement the request to print the product of the 2 primes).

I guess `foo()` is being called first. Then I am kind of lost how the sequences is being called (I know some functions return right-away and wait for the result of the "call-back" function to finish???). I am confused what is being returned right away, and what will be run in a near future to return something later in the sequences.

Comment: How are you calling these functions? Where is the `main()` function?

Comment: What is the `n` argument to `foo()` for?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `nthPrime(100, a);`, `nthPrime` will calculate the 100th prime, and then call the `a` function.

When it calls `a`, `p` will be that 100th prime.

`a` then calls `nthPrime(200, b);`. `nthPrime` will calculate the 200th prime, then call the `b` function.

When it calls `b`, its local variable `p` will be that 200th prime.

`b` needs to multiply the prime that it received by the 100th prime that was received by `a`. It's not possible to access variables in another function's scope directly. That's why `a` copies its parameter to the global variable `t` -- this provides the communication between the two callback functions.

In many other languages this would be done with closures rather than global variables, but C doesn't have closures. This limits the flexibility and capability of callbacks in C.